DataChannel only opens after initiating RTC connection twice
I'm trying to make a simple chat app in React using WebRTC datachannels, with a WebSocket signaling server. The RTCPeerConnection establishes properly and ICE candidates are being sent after initialising the peer connection using connectPeers but for some reason the data channel doesn't open until I click the button that calls connectPeers for the second time.
Below is my code so far:
let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [target, setTarget] = useState("");
  const [pcButtonDisable, setPcButtonDisable] = useState(true);
  const [currMessage, setCurrMessage] = useState("");
  const [wsConnection, setWsConnection] = useState();
  const [webSocketOutput, setWebSocketOutput] = useState(["WebSocket output:"]);
  const [peerConnectOutput, setPeerConnectOutput] = useState([
    "PeerConnect output:",
  ]);
  let dataChannel = useRef(null);

  peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = async (e) => {
    console.log(`Signaling state changed to ${peerConnection.signalingState}`);
    const lcd = peerConnection.localDescription?.sdp;
    const rcd = peerConnection.remoteDescription?.sdp;
    console.log(`Local description: ${lcd}`);
    console.log(`Remote description: ${rcd}`);
  };

  peerConnection.ondatachannel = (e) => {
    dataChannel.current = e.channel;
    console.log("Channel detected");
    dataChannel.current.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(`[Data channel] Received new message: ${e.data}`);
    };
    dataChannel.current.onopen = (e) => {
      console.log(`[Data channel] Opened!`);
      console.log(
        `Current Data channel state: ${JSON.stringify(
          dataChannel.current.readyState
        )}`
      );
      setPeerConnectOutput((output) => [...output, "Data channel connected!"]);
    };
  };

  peerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = (e) => {
    console.log(
      `ICE candidate gathering state changed: ${peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`
    );
  };

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (e) => {
    if (e.candidate) {
      console.log(`ICE candidate found, sending!`);
      wsConnection.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          target: target,
          type: "icecandidate",
          data: e.candidate,
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const hostname = "192.168.1.208";
  const port = "8000";

  const connectToWebSocket = () => {
    if (wsConnection) {
      wsConnection.close();
    }
    const socketServer = `ws://${hostname}:${port}`;
    const newConnection = new WebSocket(socketServer, "json");

    newConnection.onopen = () => {
      console.log(`Websocket connected to ${newConnection.url}`);
      setWebSocketOutput((d) => [...d, `Connected to ${newConnection.url}`]);
    };

    newConnection.onmessage = (msg) => {
      console.log(`Websocket message received: ${msg.data}`);
      switch (JSON.parse(msg.data).type) {
        case "offer":
          handleRecieveOffer(JSON.parse(msg.data), newConnection);
          break;
        case "answer":
          handleRecieveAnswer(JSON.parse(msg.data), peerConnection);
          break;
        case "icecandidate":
          handleRecieveIceCandidate(JSON.parse(msg.data), peerConnection);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };

    newConnection.onclose = () => {
      console.log("Websocket connection closed");
      setWebSocketOutput((d) => [...d, "Websocket connection closed"]);
      setWsConnection(null);
    };

    setPcButtonDisable(false);

    // Set the connection state only after defining the onopen event.
    setWsConnection(() => {
      return newConnection;
    });
  };

  /* Process for connecting peers A and B:
    - A sends offer to websocket
    - Websocket forwards offer to target client B
    - B sends answer to websocket
    - Websocket forwards answer back to A
    - A sends ICE candidate to websocket
    - Websocket forwards candidate to B
    - B sends ICE candidate
    - Websocket forwards ICE candidate to A
    - A and B establish peer-to-peer connection
  */
  const connectPeers = async () => {
    // Add dataChannel to peerConnection so it's sent with the offer
    dataChannel.current = peerConnection.createDataChannel("Channel");

    dataChannel.current.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(`[Data channel] Recieved new message ${e.data}`);
    };
    dataChannel.current.onopen = (e) => {
      if (!dataChannel) {
        console.log(`[Data channel] Opened!`);
        console.log(
          `Current Data channel state: ${JSON.stringify(
            dataChannel.current.readyState
          )}`
        );
        setPeerConnectOutput((output) => [
          ...output,
          "Data channel connected!",
        ]);
      }
    };
    console.log(
      `Data channel created: ${JSON.stringify(
        dataChannel.current
      )},${JSON.stringify(dataChannel.current.readyState)} `
    );

    // 1. A sends offer to websocket and sets local description to SDP
    console.log(`Creating offer`);
    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    console.log(`Setting local description`);
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    wsConnection.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        sender: username,
        target: target,
        type: "offer",
        data: offer,
      })
    );
  };

  // 2. Client B recieves forwarded offer from websocket
  // Client B needs to create a peerConnection and process offer
  const handleRecieveOffer = async (data, wsConnection) => {
    const offer = data.data;
    console.log(`Handling offer: ${JSON.stringify(offer)}`);

    console.log(`Setting remote description`);
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

    // Create an answer to the offer
    console.log(`Creating answer`);
    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();

    console.log(`Setting local description`);
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

    if (wsConnection) {
      wsConnection.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          sender: username,
          target: data.sender,
          type: "answer",
          data: answer,
        })
      );
    } else {
      console.log(`Error - no websocket connection established`);
    }
  };

  // 3. Client A recieves forwarded answer from websocket
  // Update peerConnection remoteDescription
  const handleRecieveAnswer = async (data, peerConnection) => {
    const answer = data.data;
    console.log(`Handling answer: ${JSON.stringify(answer)}`);
    console.log(`Setting remote description`);

    // Ensure answer is in the correct format
    const remoteDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
    console.log(
      `Current Data channel state: ${JSON.stringify(
        dataChannel.current.readyState
      )}`
    );
  };

  const handleRecieveIceCandidate = async (candidate, peerConnection) => {
    console.log(`Received ICE Candidate ${JSON.stringify(candidate)}`);
    // const iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(candidate);
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  };

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (dataChannel) {
      dataChannel.current.send(currMessage);
    }
  };

  return (
...
        <section id="buttons">
          {/* WebSocket connection */}
          <section className="button-container">
            <button onClick={connectToWebSocket}>Connect to WebSocket</button>
            <div className="button-output">
              {webSocketOutput.map((elem, idx) => {
                return <li key={idx}>{elem}</li>;
              })}
            </div>
            <div className="button-output">
              Current connection: {wsConnection ? wsConnection.url : "none"}
            </div>
          </section>

          {/* RTC Peer connection */}
          <section className="button-container">
            <button onClick={connectPeers} disabled={pcButtonDisable}>
              Initialise RTC Peer Connection
            </button>
            <div className="button-output">
              {peerConnectOutput.map((elem, idx) => {
                return <li key={idx}>{elem}</li>;
              })}
            </div>
          </section>
        </section>
...
  );
}

I'm fairly sure that the dataChannel is supposed to open the first time I connect the peers based on the guides I've read online, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, when it does open the second time, it console logs that it's opened twice in a row.
